# How use :hover in :last-child in material-ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React with material-ui and have a menu component with a list, the last item in this menu is different from the others, I using :last-child and it is functional, the problem is when I try using :hover in that last element.

Style:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
menu: {
  textDecoration: 'none',
  color: theme.palette.navy.default,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  textTransform: 'uppercase',
  '&:last-child': {
    background: theme.palette.orange.default,
    borderRadius: '5em',
    color: theme.palette.white.default,
    // using hover in the last child item not work
    '&:hover': {
      background: theme.palette.green.default,
    },
  },
 },
}));
```

Component:

```js
...
const classes = useStyles();

<MenuList>
    {menu.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuItem selected={false} key={index} className={classes.menu}>
            {item.title}
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</MenuList>
```

Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like,

```
menu: {
  textDecoration: 'none',
  color: theme.palette.navy.default,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  textTransform: 'uppercase',
  '&:last-child': {
    background: theme.palette.orange.default,
    borderRadius: '5em',
    color: theme.palette.white.default,
    
  },
   // using hover outside with the last child
    '&:last-child:hover': {
      background: theme.palette.green.default,
    },
 },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new component where I retested the options than did not work. I included @Sanish Joseph's answer that did not work previously and, this time with this new component, it worked.

In context, I created a menu mapping objects array and each object has another objects array with the submenus. I was discarding elements until I found the problem. In the Popper component that I use to display the submenus, there is a property called "disablePortal". This property was causing that "hover" in the "last-child" to not work.